# Table Valued Function not returning resule on Ajax query

Tags: table-valued-parameters

[HttpPost]

```
    public JsonResult TestViewOne(int v_int)
    {  
        using (DBModel db = new DBModel())
        {
            db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            var rt = db.ChkFn2(v_int).FirstOrDefault().RetVal;
        }
        return Json(data: rt, behavior: JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The above code is not working and the solutions earlier given has been tried, but no success!

Comment: "the code is not working" is not very specific. Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53637041/edit) to let us know what the expected result is and how your code fails to achieve it? [Reading this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may be useful

Comment: The above code is being called by Ajax call passing thev_int parameter. It does not return the desired result and throws error on ajax.

Comment: The code does not even compile (I assume it's C#): rt is defined within the inner using scope but you use it outside. "throws error" is a bit better than "is not working" and could be improved further by writing which error you get.